# How do I convert a datetime (w/timezone) to a "month, day" string  in ruby /  rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems

I'm displaying user messages on a page and for each user that UserA has sent a message to or received one from has a created_at time.

For each conversation thread I want to display the date of the lastest message in the thread. I'm pulling the created_at time and it's showing like this:

```
2012-02-08 09:56:34 UTC
```

if I add to_date at the end of created_at I can get the date to show this way:

```
2012-02-08
```

I'd like to know an easy method for converting either one of those into something like this:

```
February 8

8 February

February 8th

8th February
```

and if message not created_at in current year then display the year with the date

```
e.g. February 8, 2006
```

Kind regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [strftime](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#method-i-strftime) method to format the date. You can say `created_at.strftime("%B -d")` for `Febraury 8` for example.

Comment: Thanks, I was using it wrong.. Originally I was passing the created_at date into the strftime method. Silly.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [to_formatted_s](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateTime.html#method-i-to_formatted_s)

If you put it in an initialier:

```
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:month_and_day] = lambda { |time| Time.now.year == time.year ? time.strftime("%B #{time.day.ordinalize}") : time.strftime("%B #{time.day.ordinalize}, %Y")}
```

your views can then use the correct format:

```
created_at.to_s(:month_and_day)
```